# Problems with ggplot2 graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following questions -

Q1 How can I make the years appear on x axis as 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014 and so on (earlier they were showing up as 2012.5 etc. which has disappeared now for reason I do not know)

Q2 Is there any way to create a small gap between the red and blue bars for aesthetic purposes

Q3 Is there anyway to make the text on top of the bars bolder or thicker?
Thank you

Data -

```r
graph_text <- structure(list(percentage = c(57.14, 29.76, 69.32, 28.41, 57.89,                                        34.21, 58.59, 33.33, 48.42, 42.11, 59.77, 29.89, 72.13, 18.03,                                        53.33, 33.33, 55.1, 40.82, 46.55, 37.93), year = c(2020L, 2020L,                                                                                           2019L, 2019L, 2018L, 2018L, 2017L, 2017L, 2016L, 2016L, 2015L,                                                                                           2015L, 2014L, 2014L, 2013L, 2013L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2011L                                       ), gender = c("male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female",                                                      "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male",                                                      "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female"                                       )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Code -

```r
ymax <- max(graph_text$percentage)
ggplot(aes(x=year, y=percentage, color = gender, fill=gender), data = graph_text) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_text(aes(label = percentage), size = 4, position = position_dodge(width = 1.1), vjust=-0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 1.4*ymax))
```

Session info -

```r
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
Matrix products: default
locale:[1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=English_India.1252    
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
loaded via a namespace (and not attached): 
[1] fansi_0.5.0      assertthat_0.2.1 dplyr_1.0.6      crayon_1.4.1     utf8_1.2.1       
[6] grid_4.1.0       R6_2.5.0         DBI_1.1.1        lifecycle_1.0.0  gtable_0.3.0    
[11] magrittr_2.0.1   scales_1.1.1     ggplot2_3.3.3    pillar_1.6.1     rlang_0.4.11    
[16] generics_0.1.0   vctrs_0.3.8      ellipsis_0.3.2   tools_4.1.0      glue_1.4.2      
[21] purrr_0.3.4      munsell_0.5.0    compiler_4.1.0   pkgconfig_2.0.3  colorspace_2.0-1
[26] tidyselect_1.1.1 tibble_3.1.2
```

[image]

Comment: Is `graph_text` supposed to be `email` (or vice versa)?

Comment: Yes, graph_text is same as email.

Comment: (1) You are missing a `)` to close out your `aes(...`. (2) When I do this, I see years on the x-axis.

Comment: Thanks; is there any way to make the years appear as 2012,2013 vs 2012.5?

Comment: `scale_x_continuous` supports the `breaks=` argument for you to specify where the ticks are placed.

Comment: `scale_x_continuous` also supports `n.breaks=` to define the number of breaks, `+scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10)` (8 looks good with your data too),.

Comment: It's really better if you can pick 1 question per post. Each of these questions individually has (almost certainly) been covered on SO before, but it's hard to mark a duplicate when you ask 3 questions at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `year` to `factor` then you will get clean numbers for year:

```
ggplot(email, aes(x=factor(year), y=percentage, color = gender, fill=gender)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab(" ") +
  geom_text(aes(label = percentage), size = 4, position = position_dodge(width = 1.1), vjust=-0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 1.4*ymax))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Q1: Use the breaks argument in scale_x_continuous. For example, you could create a sequence of values from 2011 to 2020 (see code below). Here is a [reference for scale_x_continuous](https://ggplot2tor.com/scales/scale_x_continuous)

Q2: Use position_dodge() instead of "dodge" and make the width larger than the width of the bins. By default the width of the bins is set to .9 (see ?geom_bar).

Q3 Use the fontface argument in geom_text (fontface = "bold")

```
ggplot(aes(x=year, y=percentage, color = gender, fill=gender), data = graph_text) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = .8), width = .7, 
           stat='identity') +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_text(aes(label = percentage), size = 4, 
            fontface = "bold",
            position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust=-0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 1.4*ymax),
                     expand = expansion(0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2011, 2020, 1))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORiBX.png)